# Project Management Software

Tags: project-management

So I'm on a mac.  And I love Bento.  But then I thought, "Wouldn't it be great if there was software for project management specific to film?!"

Then I thought of coming here.  So...is there any film-specific project management software a la Bento?

Comment: You can kind of make Bento into whatever you want, that's the point of it. If you need more power there is always its big brother, FileMaker Pro. Problem with off-the-shelf software is that it's usually either far to broad or far too specific. Bento is a pretty quick way to throw together a system of your own that does exactly what you want. Might be happier that way. 

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these tools:

- [Audiostudiomanager](http://www.audiostudiomanager.com/): good starting point w. inventory management.
- [Basecamp](https://basecamp.com/) (prev. 37signals):  general tool for project management, simple but effective.
- [Studio Suite](http://www.studiosuite.com/): dedicated studio project, inventory and contacts management

Comment: And http://www.studiosuite.com/

Answer (score 0):

I am a huge bento fan and have used it as sort of an internal project / asset management tool for games. I wish there was something cross platform + web-based clients could hook into and view / edit records. Not sure about a film specific tool or workflow. Great thread .. I'm interested in hearing what others might have to say.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Pixar have used a product called shotgun which is fairly neat, although quite an intense learning curve.  Trello is also good, its quite general though but very flexible!

Answer (score 0):

I have used Trello for a couple of simple projects - it's easy to use and was effective for small-scale management.

https://trello.com/